Django dropdown menu with logout, change password
`
{% csrf_token %}

 `
I want to make the logout page in a drop down list, but I can't do this. The logout page only works with the above code. The path is: path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(next_page="login"), name="logout"). How can I solve this?


  {% csrf_token %}
  
